# Where is disable_if in C++0x?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11, enable-if

Boost has both `enable_if` and `disable_if`, but C++0x seems to be missing the latter. Why was it left out? Are there meta-programming facilities in C++0x that allow me to build `disable_if` in terms of `enable_if`?

---

Oh, I just noticed that `std::enable_if` is basically `boost::enable_if_c`, and that there is no such thing as `boost::enable_if` in C++0x.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the risk of seeming stupid, just do `!expression` instead of `expression` in the bool template parameter in `enable_if` to make it behave like a `disable_if`? Of course if that idea works, you could just expand on it to write a class with `disable_if`-like behavior?

Ok, I believe you could implement `disable_if` like this:

```
template <bool B, typename T = void>
struct disable_if {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct disable_if<true,T> {
};
```

Comment: Yes, I just realized `enable_if` takes a `bool` instead of a type, so negating the condition is trivial. Still, it would make the code more readable to have `disable_if`.

Comment: Ok, I gave writing a disable_if a shot, while I do believe it to be correct, my meta-programming abilities are lacking a bit.

Comment: Looks good to me (except for the missing semicolon after the `typedef` in line 3). I would probably reverse the logic, i.e. make an empty general `struct` and then specialize that for `false`, but that's just a matter of opinion/style, not correctness :)

Comment: Not quite.  Both enable_if and disable_if can take bool metafunctions as the first parameter.  For instance, you can write "disable_if< is_same<T,someclass>>" in addition to "disable_if<is_same<T,someclass>::value>".  You've got the latter done though.

Comment: I'm wrong...partially.  You've implemented disable_if_c.  You can't pass bool values to disable_if, only bool metafunctions.  disable_if is of course trivially implemented in terms of disable_if_c.

Comment: But when I go look up the current C++ draft and look in table 53, enable_if is shown as taking a boolean value like enable_if_c in Boost. So obviously there's a difference there?

Comment: Noah fell into the same trap as I did :)

Comment: This can be written more simply as: `template<bool B, typename T = void> using disable_if = std::enable_if<!B, T>;`

Comment: using `std::enable_if<!expression>` in VS2013 seems to cause an unrecoverable compiler error.