# std::enable_if string/char type

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“What happened to my SFINAE” redux: conditional template class members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531989/what-happened-to-my-sfinae-redux-conditional-template-class-members)

Why can't I pass other parameters to my template class? I'm trying to enable a specific parameter only if the type passed is a literal type. If it isn't, accept other types but do not enable the Case-Sensitive parameter.

Why does the below not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_literal
{
   enum{value = false};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<char>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<char*>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<>
struct is_literal<const char*>
{
   enum{value = true};
};

template<typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
struct is_literal<std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>>
{
   enum
   {
      value = true
   };
};

template<typename T>
class Test
{
    public:
        bool Contains(T DataType, typename std::enable_if<is_literal<T>::value, bool>::type  CaseSensitive = true);
};

template<typename T>
bool Test<T>::Contains(T DataType, typename std::enable_if<is_literal<T>::value, bool>::type CaseSensitive)
{
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    Test<int> F;    //This line gives errors.. It gives none if I pass char, char*, const char*, std::string.
    F.Contains(1);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please paste it in (exactly) and indicate which line it refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE can only occur when substitution is performed during overload resolution. That means that you *must* have a function template. In this case, you have a non-template function in a class template. That does not work. You can add a default template parameter to fix this.

```
template <typename U = T>
bool Contains(U DataType, typename std::enable_if<is_literal<U>::value, bool>::type  CaseSensitive = true);
```

Comment: Hmm I couldn't get that working. I did:

template<typename T>
template <typename U>
bool Test<T>::Contains(U DataType, typename std::enable_if<is_literal<U>::value, bool>::type  CaseSensitive)
{
    return true;
}

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames : [Works here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1b6ow5$0).

Comment: Hmm but then I get:
|61|error: no matching function for call to 'Test<int>::Contains(int)'

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames : You never made a specialization for `int`, so that's exactly what _should_ happen...